# Observable.FromAsync() - how to handle CancelationToken

Tags: c#, task, system.reactive

Consider calling `async Load` method using  Select/Switch pattern:

```cs
Task Load(CancellationToken ct) { .. }

sourceObservable
   .Select(val => Observable.FromAsync(Load))
   .Switch()
```

Is it possible to write an operator, that will handle all exceptions, when the
`CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` is true?

Unfortunatelly, I can't do just:

```
Observable.FromAsync(Load)
  .Catch<TaskCancelledException>(Observable.Empty<Unit>())
```

Because there is no guarantee that the exception caused by CancelationToken is of type `TaskCancelledException`. E.g. SqlClient throw SqlException, etc...

So basically I need equivalent of:

```
try
{
    ....
}
catch when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    return Observable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Comment: `.Select(val => Observable.FromAsync(Load))` <-- I'm unsure why you're doing that... The `val` from your `sourceObservable` won't (normally) be an `Observable` itself, it would be a DTO or some (usually immutable) event details object.

Comment: @Dai: sure, it is usually EventArgs, or a primitive type. `sourceObservable` is not higher level observable, but `.Select(val => Observable.FromAsync(Load))` or `.Select(val => Observable.FromAsync(ct => Load(val, ct)))` returns higher level observable

Comment: The `CancellationToken` is canceled automatically when the `Observable.FromAsync` sequence is unsubscribed, at which point the result of the asynchronous operation is no longer propagated through the sequence. So it's not clear to me why you want to suppress a cancellation error, which is already suppressed by the Rx mechanics. Could you include a minimal example where you are able to observe such an exception through the sequence?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: You are right. When I saw the exception being propagated, the Load method must have been called from elsewhere.

Comment: `catch when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)` <-- I don't think this is a good idea anyway - just because **a** `CancellationToken` was cancelled doesn't mean the-caught-exception _will_ be a cancellation exception nor that the exception's details can be swallowed. I know you mentioned having to special-case for `SqlException`, in which case you should specifically do `catch( SqlException sqlEx )` _and_ check the inner `SqlErrors` values.

Comment: @Dai: As Theodor mentioned, this is exactly what Switch operator is already doing out of the box.

Comment: @Dai it might not be a bad idea either. Check out this comment in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a4b8893a118357b55c0add9a39cc5aeb097a0bb8/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.ForEachAsync.cs#L408) of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`: *"The externally provided token had cancellation requested. Assume that any exceptions then are due to that, and just cancel the resulting task."* This code has been authored by Stephen Toub.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias my heart is broken, I renounce .NET - I'm switching to [Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk3qkQROb_k) for life.

Answer (score 2):

Question:

> Is it possible to write an operator, that will handle all exceptions, when the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested is true?

Answer:
**It is not needed as the exception are not propagated to the observable sequence.**

@theodor-zoulias explained it well in the comments:

> The CancellationToken is canceled when the Observable.FromAsync
> sequence is unsubscribed, at which point the result of the
> asynchronous operation is no longer propagated through the sequence.

Remember that Switch() operator automatically unsubscribes from previous inner observable (`Observable.FromAsync(Load)` in this case) when there is a new value emitted.